# Scripting curl requests in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing, curl

**What is given:**

Statistic server which gives reply on how many ip addresses within a range correspond to a given rule.

Server which is contacted through http using pattern:

```
curl http://server/p?q=(rule)+range%3A[1.0.0.0 to 1.255.255.255]
```

Server produces reply:

```
10,250
```

**The question is:**

What is the most tiny bash script code to get the list of ip sub-ranges containing 900-1000(strictly) servers corresponding to the rule (rule is a type of a server for example)?

What I need to get at the end is an output of the list of sub-ranges (e.g. 1.0.0.0 - 1.10.200.255) within global range 1.0.0.0 to 1.255.255.255 (which i feed to the server initially) where the number of hosts corresponding to the given **rule** is in between of 900-1000 items.

For example, I do:

```
./script.sh ftp 1.0.0.0 1.255.255.255
```

**I expect to receive:**

---

```
1.0.0.0         1.10.200.255    967 (should be 900< <1000) 

1.10.200.255    1.50.230.255    935 (should be 900< <1000)

...

1.200.255.255   1.255.255.255   951 (the last one could be any <1000)
```

---

And total should be equal to initial data
10,250=967+935+...+951

In other words: 
I need to split global ip range into shorter sub-ranges which contain 900-1000 results. It seams brutforce technique for the ip sub-ranges should imply, but it is not clear how to implement this.

Comment: It is unclear wether the IP-ranges are arbitrary batches, or if the follow a pattern.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this, maybe?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
MY_INPUT=${@:-$(</dev/stdin)}
printf '%s\n' $MY_INPUT \
  | xargs -n2 \
  | while read LOWER UPPER; do
    printf '%s %s %s\n' \
      "$LOWER" "$UPPER" "$(curl http://server/p?q=(rule)+range%3A[$LOWER to $UPPER])" 
    done \
    | awk '{SUM+=$3; print $0} END {print "Total : " SUM}' \
    | column -t
```

just pipe your ranges into that.

If you have a file that has your ranges in it with lower bound and upper bound on each line...

```
1.1.1.1 1.2.3.4
4.5.6.7 8.9.10.11
```

...you could `script.sh < file_with_ranges.txt`

or you can `script.sh 1.0.0.0 1.10.200.255 1.10.200.255 1.50.230.255`

`MY_INPUT=${@:-$(</dev/stdin)}` is a bit of magic that let's the script accept either: values from stdin, or positional arguments.
`xargs` splits the arguments in pairs of two.
The `while`loop read the values, prints them and calls your server who responds with a number.
`awk` sums up the numbers given back by your server and prints the total when all lines are processed.
`column -t` to create a table.

So if you have a file `test` like this one...

```
1.0.0.0         1.10.200.255
1.10.200.255    1.50.230.255
1.200.255.255   1.255.255.255
```

and run `script.sh < test`, you get output like this:

```
1.0.0.0        1.10.200.255   967
1.10.200.255   1.50.230.255   935
1.200.255.255  1.255.255.255  951
Total          :              2853
```

Comment: Thanks for you code some new ideas appeared after reading. It seams I did not describe the problem in detail. What I need to get at the end is an output of the list of sub-ranges (e.g.  1.0.0.0 - 1.10.200.255) within global range 1.0.0.0 to 1.255.255.255 (which i feed to the server initially) where the number of hosts corresponding to the given rule is in between of 900-1000 items.

Comment: You should update your question accordingly.  And which rule exactly?